# Static files not served by expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have the following server (app.js) - the server is started by another file totally standard (if you think it might help, I can add it):

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as session from "express-session";
import { join } from "path";
import * as favicon from "serve-favicon";
import * as logger from "morgan";
import * as cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import { json, urlencoded } from "body-parser";
import * as uid from 'uid-safe';

var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var redis = require("redis").createClient();

const app: express.Application = express();
app.disable("x-powered-by");

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(json({limit: '10mb'}));
app.use(urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }));

app.use(favicon(join(__dirname, "/../client/dist/assets/images", "fav.ico")));

app.use('/fonts', express.static(join(__dirname + '/../client/dist/assets/fonts')));
app.use('/images', express.static(join(__dirname + '/../client/dist/assets/images')));
app.use('/stylesheets', express.static(join(__dirname + '/../client/dist/assets/stylesheets')));
app.use('/javascripts', express.static(join(__dirname + '/../client/dist/assets/javascripts')));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(join(__dirname + '/../client/node_modules')));
app.use('/static', express.static(join(__dirname + '/../client/dist')));


app.use(session(
    {
        secret: mySecret,
        store: new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: redis }),
        cookie: { maxAge: 12 * 3600000 /* hour */ },
        resave: true, saveUninitialized: true,
        genid:(req)=>{
            return req.groupID + ':' + uid.sync(18);
        },
    }
));

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', join(__dirname, '../client/dist'));


app.get("*", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.render('index', {user: req.session.user});
});
```

In my client side, I have the following (pug) index (index.pug):

```
doctype html
html
    head
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no')
        meta(http-equiv='x-ua-compatible', content='ie=edge')

        link(rel='stylesheet', type="text/css", href='/stylesheets/styles.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', type="text/css", href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-4.alpha6.min.css')

        script(type='application/javascript' src='/javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')
        script(type='application/javascript' src='/javascripts/bootstrap-4.alpha6.min.js')
    body
        // some content
```

The structure of my app is:

```
server
--app.js

client
--dist
----index.pug
----assets
------javascripts
--------jquery-3.2.1.min.js
--------bootstrap-4.alpha6.min.js
------stylesheets
--------styles.css
--------bootstrap-4.alpha6.min.css
```

The problem I'm facing is that static javascript files (such as jquery) are not served by my server while css files are properly served!

On the server side I don't see any GET request coming for the jquery/bootstrap files (while I see it for the css files) and on the browser I get the following error: `GET http://localhost:8001/javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js/ net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. I have tried with other javascript/css files and I'm getting the same behaviour - css are properly served while javascripts aren't. I don't understand what redirects I'm doing here...

I'm struggling with this issue for 3 days now :( so any help is appreciated

UPDATE:

I have reduced the server to the minimum and still having the same errors:

```
import * as express from "express";
import { join } from "path";

const app: express.Application = express();

app.use('/stylesheets', express.static(join(__dirname + '/../client/dist/assets/stylesheets')));
app.use('/javascripts', express.static(join(__dirname + '/../client/dist/assets/javascripts')));


app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', join(__dirname, '../client/dist'));

app.get("*", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.render('index');
});


export { app }
```

Comment: Is your indentation wrong for your assets? As your paths are `/dist/assets` but based on your app structure looks like it should be `/client/assets`

Comment: @James my bad... the mistake was in my question, I corrected the file structures.

Comment: Can you try href='./stylesheets/styles.css' and src='./javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'

Comment: @hurricane same problem... does someone understand the redirect error?

Comment: @ncohen I got the problem. Actually you are serving these files twice. Just use app.use('/static', express.static(join(__dirname + '/../client/dist'))); this.

Comment: @ncohen cool, the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` issue seems to be your problem, it could be the `static` route that's conflicting with the previous ones?

Comment: @hurricane not working... What was your idea? `/static` is for files in the `static` folder and my js files starts with `/javascripts`

Comment: I have tried to keep only the `/javascripts` and the `/stylesheets` routes but I'm having the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by clearing the cache of my browser (Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

In my projects i just use one folder for serving application.

**Folder structure**

[image]

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor-831caab4c1.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app-372f46a56e.css">

<script src="scripts/vendor-1acdaaa566.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app-73f1753f0e.js"></script>
```

**server.js** (this is must be in /dist folder too. )

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('/*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

If you want to use server.js outside of the dist folder you can use /dist path for all files.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.get('/*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor-831caab4c1.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/styles/app-372f46a56e.css">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! After 3 days trying to solve this problem I have finally found the cause... I cleared the cache of my browser and everything is working now! Thanks Chrome :(